# VS 2012: Change color of selected text when context-menu is open

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I know that the color scheme for the Text Editor can be changed at TOOLS -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

However, what I can't find is this: When selecting a chunk of text with the mouse, and right clicking on that selection, the background color for the selection changes. Right now, that color matches the dark background of the Text Editor, which makes it look like nothing is selected.

**How can I change the background color of selected text when the right-click context menu is open?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `InactiveSelectedText` option.

A part from this, I want to inform you to look at [this site](http://studiostyl.es/) where you can find many premade themes with accurately choosen colors